# how to logout from lightning community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, customer-portal, lightning-community, logout

We're currently using this template:

`Customer Account Portal Spring ’18`

What I want to happen is simple: from my lightning component's controller, I should be able to:

1. logout from the current session
2. redirect to our login page

But what's happening is, whenever I call `/secur/logout.jsp`, it redirects to `https://www.salesforce.com/ap/?ir=1`, but the session isn't really destroyed, in fact, it just redirects, and the session remains alive. When I go back to the page I came from, I can still access it, perfectly indicating that the session hasn't been deleted.

I have already tried a lot of posts here in stackexchange. I have tried:

- `location.href="https://<site>.cs##.force.com/secur/logout.jsp?retUrl=google.com"`
- `window.location.href="https://<site>.cs##.force.com/secur/logout.jsp?startUrl=http://google.com"`
- `window.location.replace("<site>/secur/logout.jsp")`
- ```
  var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
      urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": "https://<site>.cs##.force.com/secur/logout.jsp"
      });
  urlEvent.fire();
  ```

I even tried the logout functionality of the omni-toolkit, just out of desperation, but it still fails.

I tried peeking at salesforce's logout handler, and they have this helper functions there:

```
handleForceLogout: function(a, b) {
    var d, c = b.getParam("logoutUrl");
    d = c ? Promise.resolve(c) : new Promise($A.getCallback(function(b,
        d) {
        var c = a.get("c.getLogoutURL");
        c.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            "SUCCESS" === a.getState() ? b(a.getReturnValue()) : ((a = a.getError()) && a[0] && a[0].message && $A.error(a[0].message), b("/secur/logout.jsp"))
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(c)
    }.bind(this)));
    c = function() {
        var a = $A.storageService.getStorages(),
            b = [],
            c;
        for (c in a) a[c].isPersistent() && b.push($A.storageService.deleteStorage(c).then(void 0, function(a) {
            $A.log("At logout, deleting storage '" + c + "' threw an err: ", a)
        }));
        b.push(this.beaconLib.BeaconLibrary.handleLogoutAsync());
        a = $A.getCallback(function() {
            try {
                sessionStorage.clear()
            } catch (a) {}
            d.then($A.getCallback(function(a) {
                this.redirect(a)
            }.bind(this)))
        }).bind(this);
        Promise.all(b).then(a, a)
    }.bind(this);
    this.runPlugins(a, c)
},
redirect: function(a) {
    location.href = a
}
```

It looks the same as what I'm trying to implement, but their code works perfectly, mine doesn't.

Comment: looks like you have to raise a case with SF. Its a security flaw from their end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use below code to redirect to community login page :

```
window.location.replace("<community-domain>/secur/logout.jsp?retUrl=<redirect-URL>");
```

Eg:

1. `window.location.replace("/testPortal/secur/logout.jsp?retUrl=%2Flogin");`
2. `window.location.replace("https://mycommunity-domain.com/secur/logout.jsp?retUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmycommunity-domain.com%2Flogin");`

Comment: I see now. The magic is I have to indicate the `/<portal>` before the `/secur/logout.jsp`. Thanks @Nandan.

Comment: worth adding that you can do this with a standard community button by linking the button to "https://<community-domain>.force.com/secur/logout.jsp". i.e. if my community domain is "mycarexchange-developer-edition.na53.force.com" my logout link would be "https://mycarexchange-developer-edition.na53.force.com/secur/logout.jsp"

Answer (score 2):

I spent some time to find a nice solution for custom logout. **All you need to do is only fire event from the aura.**
The community has event listener in **logoutHandler.js** file.

```
 $A.get("e.force:logout").fire();
```

[image]

This solution is a standard one and doesn't require any hard coding.

More details and the whole code you can find here: https://beyondthecloud.dev/blog/custom-logout-in-experience-cloud

Answer (score 1):

Found info elsewhere if it may help: https://simplysalesforce.com/2016/02/24/custom-logout-button-on-lightning-component-in-community/

```
window.location.replace("https://YourCommunityDomain/servlet/networks/switch?startURL=%2Fsecur%2Flogout.jsp");
```

Comment: Looked promising, but unfortunately it didn't work for me.