# How to logout from a Digital Experience (AKA Community) using LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, login, digital-experience, logout

There are multiple posts about using URLs of this nature:

```
.../secur/logout.jsp?retUrl=...
```

e.g. [how to logout from lightning community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212636/how-to-logout-from-lightning-community) to logout. And for LWC, there are these functions:

```
import getLogoutUrl from '@salesforce/apex/applauncher.IdentityHeaderController.getLogoutUrl';
import getLoginUrl from '@salesforce/apex/system.Network.getLoginUrl';
```

mentioned in [Create a Logout Link Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/advanced_custom_logout.htm).

But after several hours of trying many permutations, I couldn't get a solution that both did the logout and left the user back at the experience login rather than the general Salesforce login. The problem might be this known issue [Logout URL in community is not working if there is only one authentication provider login option](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000wy0kQAA&_ga=2.63359660.282681954.1654868224-2035533257.1650994074).

Is there a simple workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the workaround I found using the very convenient [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API to do the logout part:

```
async logout() {

    // Logout
    const logoutUrl = await getLogoutUrl();
    await fetch(logoutUrl);

    // Login page (or could navigate to some other URL)
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__loginPage',
        attributes: { actionName: 'login' }
    });
}
```

I found that `getLoginUrl` did nothing useful.

Comment: Epic, clean and functional!

Answer (score 0):

Logout should be done using the named page with the logout action, it's a lot like the example above but I would suggest to do this:

```
import {LightningElement} from "lwc";
import {NavigationMixin} from "lightning/navigation";

const LOGOUTPAGEREF = {
    type: "comm__loginPage",
    attributes: {
        actionName: "logout"
    }
};

export default class ComLogoutButton extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    logout() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](LOGOUTPAGEREF);
    }
}
```

the template can look like this:

```
<template>
    <a onclick={logout}>
        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:logout" alternative-text="Logout"> </lightning-icon>
    </a>
</template>
```

for everyone else's convenience I have created a repo with a quick deploy option here:
https://github.com/Henk3000/communityLogoutButton